# Possibly sending data incorrectly? Posting a form submission to PHP and then to an external API and response says included field is missing

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, post

I have a form that I want to submit to an external API. To do this without getting a cross-origin error I found a way to pass data from the form to a PHP file and then from there I can make the POST to the outside API and return the response to my client file and read the contents of the response.

However I'm getting 400 errors with a message saying "password is missing" when password is definitely not missing. Is there something wrong with my php or javascript that's causing the data not to be sent correctly? Please let me know if you see something wrong. I'm new to php.

Another thing worth noting is that when I run this code it still hits the `success` case in the JavaScript instead of hitting the error case. Which makes it extra strange. The response definitely doesn't give an object with properties that are expected.

the error looks like this: ""jsonCode":402,"message":"402 Missing password","requestID":"arhwerhwarawtr"}

html form

```
<form action="hello.php" class="js-ajax-php-json" method="post" accept-charset="utf-8">
    <input type="hidden" id="name" name="name" value="johndoe">
    <input type="hidden" id="password" name="password" value="sfhsrtjsgargjk">
    <input type="text" id="id" name="id" value="" placeholder="username" />
    <input type="text" id="secret" name="secret" value="" placeholder="password" />
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit form"  />
</form>
```

php

```
<?php
if (is_ajax()) {
if (isset($_POST["action"]) && !empty($_POST["action"])) { //Checks if action value exists
    $action = $_POST["action"];
    switch($action) { //Switch case for value of action
    case "test": callAPI('POST','www.sample.com', $action); break;
    }
}
}

//Function to check if the request is an AJAX request
function is_ajax() {
return isset($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) && strtolower($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) == 'xmlhttprequest';
}



function callAPI($method, $url, $data){
    $curl = curl_init();

    switch ($method){
        case "POST":
            curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
            if ($data)
                curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);
            break;
        case "PUT":
            curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "PUT");
            if ($data)
                curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);                              
            break;
        default:
            if ($data)
                $url = sprintf("%s?%s", $url, http_build_query($data));
    }

    // OPTIONS:
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(
        'Content-Type: application/json',
    ));
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPAUTH, CURLAUTH_BASIC);

    // EXECUTE:
    $result = curl_exec($curl);
    if(!$result){die("Connection Failure");}
    curl_close($curl);
    $result["json"] = json_encode($result);
    echo json_encode($result);
    return $result;
}
?>
```

JavaScript:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".js-ajax-php-json").submit(function(){
        var data = {
        "action": "test"
        };
        data = $(this).serialize() + "&" + $.param(data);
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            dataType: "json",
            url: "hello.php",
            data: data,
            success: function(data) {
                // manipulate response data
                // $(".the-return").html(
                // "First Value: " + data["username"] + "<br />Second Value: " + data["password"] + "<br />JSON: " + data["json"]
                // );

                console.log(data);
                // alert("Form submitted successfully.\nReturned json: " + data);
            }, error: function(data){
                alert("Form submitted unsuccessfully.\nReturned json: " + data.jsonCode + data.message);
            }
        });
        return false;
    });

});
```

Comment: Ryan can you please to echo the $_POST['password'], just to make sure that everything is smooth with the POST request.

Comment: @DorPerez should I put that in the body of my `callAPI` POST case?

Comment: Yes, just for test purpose.

Comment: @DorPerez I actually have found a typo in the code that was on my front end that caused the password not to be sent. It did not match the code posted here so there must have been a problem when moving it to production. However now I am getting a 500 Internal Server Error.

Comment: 500 Error can be related to a couple of things, but I advise you to check this one because you mention the production. File Permissions. Check that your PHP processor have access to the PHP file.

Comment: Very strange. The error has come back, however I didn't make any changes. After the 500 error I gave it some time (thinking I'd been making too many outbound requests. This code is hosted on my university's server), however the 402 error has returned. When I echo the $_POST['password'] nothing happens, at least on the frontend. Because it is a university server I can't directly watch the php file as it runs in the backend.

Comment: So the problem here is really about $_POST['password'], please show me the output of var_dump($_POST);